# Number Variables are always undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, web, stopwatch

i want to build a small stopwatch in javascript. The Problem is that the variables that store the time (seconds, minutes, hours) are always undefined and dont increase. I dont finde the misstake! Whats the problem here? Any solutions?

```
Test.timer = {
    seconds : 0,
    minutes : 0, 
    hours : 0,
    timeout : null,
    running : 0,

    tick: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.timeout = setTimeout(self.add, 1000);
    },

    add: function() {
        var self = this;

        self.seconds++;
        if (self.seconds >= 60) {
            self.seconds = 0;
            self.minutes++;
            if (self.minutes >= 60) {
                self.minutes = 0;
                self.hours++;
            }
        }

        var time = document.getElementById("time");
        time.textContent = (self.hours ? (self.hours > 9 ? self.hours : "0" + self.hours) : "00") + ":" + (self.minutes ? (self.minutes > 9 ? self.minutes : "0" + self.minutes) : "00") + ":" + (self.seconds > 9 ? self.seconds : "0" + self.seconds);

        self.tick();
    },

    start: function() {
        var self = this;
        if (self.running == 0) {
            self.running = 1;
            self.tick();
        }
    },

    stop: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.running = 0;
        clearTimeout(self.timeout);
    }
};
```

The result i get in the time label is: "00:00:0NaN"! Please help..

Comment: I don't even know where to start.  First, your stopwatch will lose time as it runs.  You need to store the starting time and then in your updates the time to show is "now - starting time".  Second, there's no reason to keep track of hours/minutes/seconds in something like this.  Keep track of seconds and then compute hours and minutes from there.  Third, use ".toFixed" to get two-digit leading zero representation: seconds.toFixed(2) for example.  Fourth, please oh please quit using "self".  It's "this" in javascript, if you're renaming it in every function there's an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the scope will be window and not timer

```
self.timeout = setTimeout(self.add, 1000);
```

needs to be

```
self.timeout = setTimeout( function() { self.add(); }, 1000);
```

or

```
self.timeout = setTimeout(this.add.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: +1, but: *"Because the scope will be window and not timer"* It's not *scope*, but yes, the problem (as you know!) is `this` isn't what the OP is expecting when `add` is called...

Answer (score 1):

Your code in `tick` doesn't do anything to ensure that `this` within `add` is a reference to your object. In fact, your code is functionally identical to this:

```
tick: function() {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.add, 1000);
},
```

In JavaScript, `this` is set primarily by how a function is *called* rather than where it's defined. The `self` trick you were using would work if `add` closed over `self` but it doesn't.

Because `timer` is a singleton, you could just use `Test.timer` everywhere you use `this` and resolve the problem that way.

```
add: function() {
    var self = Test.timer;
    // ...the rest is unchanged...
},
```

*(And similar other places you've used `this` or `var self = this;`)*

If you don't want to do that (or if you need to do this with non-singletons in the future), you can use ES5's `Function#bind` (which can be shimmed/polyfilled on older browsers):

```
tick: function() {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.add.bind(this), 1000);
},
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, will call the original function with `this` set to the value you give it.

More to explore *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)